# Taylor expansion of arctan(1+x)

Tags: taylor-expansion

Good evening! I began to learn about **Taylor expansions** and have to manage such a topic for Monday.

I'm looking for the Taylor expansion at the second order: $DL_2(0)$ of  $f(x)=\arctan(1+x)$.

Having $f(0)=\pi/4$, $f'(0)=1/2$, $f''(0)=-1/2$

Why does $\arctan(1+x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}+o_o(x^2)$

How such a formula was achieved?

It really doesn't look like the given formula:

> $\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+...+(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+...+(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}+o(x^{2n+2})$

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ and $\arctan(1+x)$ are different functions and have different Taylor expansions (at $x =  0$) ...

Comment: I think the best way of demonstrating that these are both valid representations is to actually go out and compute the first few derivatives of each function, and write out the formal Taylor series. You'll see how both work.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Power Series Expansion for Real Arctangent Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Real_Arctangent_Function) in proofwiki.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll prove the last line of your post, maybe I'll not completely answer your question.

Assuming $|x|<1$, let
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
Since it is a power series, we can take the limit under the sign of derivative:

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n x^{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-x^2\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} $$
The last sum is a geometric series; it follows
$$f(x)=\int_0^x\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}=\arctan x$$
This works $\forall x$ s.t. $|x|<1$.
Now if you want $\arctan (1+x)$, if you know Taylor formula you can just translate.